# C#: How do I iterate through two listBoxes individually?

Tags: c#, for-loop, listbox

I am trying to iterate through two listBoxes for a program I am coding. Both listBoxes will have a different item count inside of it.

Basically, I want my program to get the selectedItem from one listBox and use the string or text from that item to replace the text from EACH and EVERY single item in the other listBox.

Once it's done using the selectedItem from the original listBox for all the items in the other listBox, I want it to go to the next item in the original listBox and do the same process all over again.

It should repeat this UNTIL it has gone through ALL of the items in the original listBox.

Hopefully that made sense....

Here is some example code I made. I created two for loops so that it could iterate through both listBoxes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBoxOriginal.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string linkurl = listBoxOriginal.Items[i].ToString() + "..";
    listBoxNewListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

    for (int o = 0; o < listBoxNewListBox.Items.Count; o++)
    {
        string s = listBoxNewListBox.Items[o] as string;
        string newurl = s.Replace("DOMAIN", linkurl);
        listBoxNewListBox.SelectedIndex++;
    }
}
```

My issue is, when the inner for loop finishes iterating completely it errors out. I know the error is because it reached the end of the listBox and can't go any further, but I don't know how else to iterate through the listBox without having the items selected.

What it should do is, once it reaches the end of "listBoxNewListBox" it should go to the next item in "listBoxOriginal", and perform the same process all over again until it's done going through every item in "listBoxOriginal".

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is because of `SelectedIndex` at list. I think it's just going to far.

Here is a little modification:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBoxOriginal.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string linkurl = listBoxOriginal.Items[i].ToString() + "..";

    for (int o = 0; o < listBoxNewListBox.Items.Count; o++)
    {
        string s = listBoxNewListBox.Items[o] as string;
        string newurl = s.Replace("DOMAIN", linkurl);
        listBoxNewListBox.SelectedIndex = o;
    }
}
```

Here is explanation:

When in inner loop you are doing this operation: `listBoxNewListBox.SelectedIndex++` you are setting this index as 1 more than index of loop. That means, if we look at very last iteration of inner loop, this index is set with value which is already to high. This is probably reason why application throws an exception.